# ManagedProperty not injected in @FacesConverter

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, converters, managed-bean

I'm trying to inject a ManagedBean in my FacesConverted the following way:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = Group.class)
public class GroupConverter implements Converter {

@ManagedProperty("#{groupService}")
private GroupService groupService;

@Override
public Group getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent arg1,
        String groupName) {
    return groupService.findGroupByName(groupName);
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object group) {
    return ((Group) group).getName();
}

public GroupService getGroupService() {
    return groupService;
}

public void setGroupService(GroupService groupService) {
    this.groupService = groupService;
}

}
```

The problem is that groupService isn't being injected and I get a NullPointerEx. Shouldn't it be autowired automatically since it's also a ManagedBean? It all works when I change "getAsObject" to "return new Group();" obviously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is likely that you are not resolving the [managed bean name](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html#name%28%29).

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myConverter")
@RequestScoped
@FacesConverter(value = "myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
```

For example, consider these two components:

```
        <h:inputText converter="myConverter" value="#{foo.prop}" />
        <h:inputText converter="#{myConverter}" value="#{bar.prop}" />
```

When the converter is set on the first component, it will be created by [Application.createConverter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#createConverter%28java.lang.String%29). **A converter is not a managed bean**. The same rules apply if you [match a converter by type](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#createConverter%28java.lang.Class%29).

In the second component, a value expression is used to return a class that implements [Converter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html). This uses the usual managed bean mechanisms. In this case, the `@FacesConverter` annotation is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea that a converter isnt a bean even if I annotate it as one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `#{myConverter}` saved me lots of time!