# JSF - Cannot inject Spring Data JPA repository into Converter

Tags: spring, jsf, converters, inject

I am certain I have got this working in the past, but it doesn't want to work today.

**Example:**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "inputConverter")
public class InputConverter implements Converter {


    private InputRepository inputRepository;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {

        List<Input> allInputs = inputRepository.findAll();

        for(Input input : allInputs) {
            if(input.getInputName().equals(arg2)) {
                return input;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        Input input = (Input) arg2;
        return input.getInputName();
    }


    public InputRepository getInputRepository() {
        return inputRepository;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setInputRepository(InputRepository inputRepository) {
        this.inputRepository = inputRepository;
    }

}
```

**Result:**

Null pointer exception on the itemRepository.findAll() call - the @Inject didn't set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found on another post: [ManagedProperty not injected in @FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135942/managedproperty-not-injected-in-facesconverter)

As I am using @Inject and the injected JPA Repository is managed by Spring, it was neccessary to use `@Component("itemConverter"), @Scope("session")` instead of `@ManagedBean`.